# Problem with send POST from Vue.js to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, vue.js

I try send post from multi rows in Vue.js to api in Laravel. I thing that in foreach rows should by insterted to DB, but i'm in error ;)
This my code in vue:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        const_expenses: []
      }
    },
    methods:{
      fetchExpenses(){
        this.$http.get('http://home-local.pl/public/api/expenses')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(result => this.const_expenses = result)
      },
      addNewRow() {
        this.const_expenses.push({
          mounth: '',
          year: '',
          name: '',
          amount: '',
          status: 0
        });
      },
      saveExpenses() {
        this.$http.post('http://home-local.pl/public/api/expenses', this.const_expenses)
          .then(() => {
            this.$router.push({path: '/expenses'});
          });
      },
    },
    created: function () {
      this.fetchExpenses();
    }
  };
</script>
```

Code in API:

```
public function setConstExpense($expence)
{
    Log::info($expence);
    foreach ($expence as $e)
    {
        ConstExpense::create($e->all());
    }
    return response()->json(['created' => true],201);
}
```

In log i have:

```
[2020-07-27 20:57:59] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'mounth' => '1',
    'year' => '2020',
    'name' => '1',
    'amount' => '0.01',
    'status' => 0,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'mounth' => '2',
    'year' => '2020',
    'name' => '2',
    'amount' => '0.02',
    'status' => 0,
  ),
)  
[2020-07-27 20:57:59] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'mounth' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `const_expenses` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2020-07-27 20:57:59, 2020-07-27 20:57:59))
```

etc, etc

Why I can't instert this items into DB. When I make test api in Postman all is ok.

Comment: Have you added `mounth` field in `$fillable` array ?

Comment: yes
`protected $fillable = ['name','mounth', 'year', 'amount', 'status']; `

Answer (score 0):

update your

```
config/database.php
```

file and set `'strict' => false` for your connection.